# How do I know how many clients can handle a server in java

Tags: java, android, sockets, server

I have a chat application that takes up a server in java and I can access since the explorer or even in an app in android.
I need to know How many clients can be on the chat at the same time and How can I do to test the application about it?
For example I would like to simulate the connection of 100 clients, How can I do that?

This is the source of the chat application
http://www.androidhive.info/2014/10/android-building-group-chat-app-using-sockets-part-1/

Thanks

Comment: Organize a big party with 99 friends and tell them to bring their android phone. Or google for "load testing tool".

Comment: ok, thanks, you will be the first guest if I don't find how to do it.